# How to perform a segue view from custom UITableViewCell(xib) to another ViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, xib, swift2

I want to show a button on my custom UITableViewCell which takes the user to another screen on tapping on it.
I have tried following code but it doesn't work

Child view:

```
@IBAction func childScreenButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let delegate = self.delegate {
        delegate.childButtonClickedOnCell(self)
       }
    }
```

Protocol:

```
protocol childTableCellDelegate: class {
func childButtonClickedOnCell(cell: childViewCell)
}
```

Parent ViewController:

```
func childButtonClickedOnCell(cell: FeedChildViewCell) {
     self.clickedIndexPath = self.feedsTableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
     self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toNextScreen", sender: self)

}
```

while I'm testing the break point doesn't enter into "delegate.childButtonClickedOnCell(self)" on child view. Please let me know if am doing anything wrong here. Thanks!!

Comment: I assume `@IBAction func childScreenButton(sender: AnyObject) {}` is in your custom cell class? Are you setting the delegate?

Comment: yes!! IBAction func childScreenButton(sender: AnyObject) {} is in my custom cell and I am setting the delegate @DonMag

Comment: ok - so, you set a breakpoint on `if let delegate = self.delegate {`? But tapping the button does not get to that breakpoint?

Comment: yes I set a break point at   if let delegate = self.delegate {   but it is not going inside the if-condition i.e, delegate.childButtonClickedOnCell(self) @DonMag

Comment: what's the value of `self.delegate` at that point?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you've got a couple things out of place, or not defined just right.

I just ran a quick test with this, and the delegate call works fine... see if you notice anything not-quite-the-same...

```
//
//  TestTableViewController.swift
//
//  Created by DonMag on 4/7/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 DonMag. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

protocol MyCellDelegate {
    func pressedButtonForMyCell(theSender: MyCell)
}

class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var theLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var theButton: UIButton!

    var delegate: MyCellDelegate?

    @IBAction func childScreenButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.pressedButtonForMyCell(theSender: self)
    }

}

class TestTableViewController: UITableViewController, MyCellDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell

        cell.theLabel.text = "\(indexPath)"
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    }

    func pressedButtonForMyCell(theSender: MyCell) {
        print("delegate called", theSender)
    }

}
```

Comment: I didn't defined delegate in parent viewController, now its working fine.. Thanks @DonMag